# OpenCV and rawkit python

Tags: python, opencv

I load a cr2 file in argv... then I want to convert it to an opencv format so i can use it in the app (not save it as a file). It is loaded first with Rawkit.

```
raw_image = Raw(sys.argv[1])
buffered_image = np.array(raw_image.to_buffer())
image = Image.frombytes('RGB', (raw_image.metadata.width, raw_image.metadata.height), buffered_image)

image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

That is my attempt.

The image loads and looks very poor with a bunch of diagonal zigzags

In essence :I need to convert

```
image = Image.frombytes('RGB', (raw_image.metadata.width, raw_image.metadata.height), buffered_image)
```

to the same format as what it would be if i used

```
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier if you use [rawpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rawpy):

```
import rawpy
import cv2

raw = rawpy.imread("path/to/file") # access to the RAW image
rgb = raw.postprocess() # a numpy RGB array
image = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # the OpenCV image
cv2.imwrite("foo.png", image)
```

I just tried it and it worked without a problem.